# Java ResourceBundle.getBundle missing resource exception

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java and have taken some old java code and tried to get it running in the latest version of Eclipse.

The code compiles but when I run it I receive an error.

This is the line of code that is causing the error:

```
ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/system");
```

And the error I receive is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resources/system, locale en_GB
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
at com.tma.sp.flowvalidator.ThreadLauncher.<clinit>(ThreadLauncher.java:28)
```

I've searched about a bit for this error but every answer seems different.

Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: what is the directory layout in your project?

Comment: I have everything under the src folder. Within the src folder I have a resources folder with my .properties files

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/system");
> ```

The path given is relative to the package of the calling class. You need to specify an absolute path (by means of UNC-Path) by preceding a slash:

```
ResourceBundle properties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/resources/system");
```

Comment: This makes no difference. I still get the same error

Comment: @SunCol what is you operating system?  Did you spell anything correctly (including case)?

Comment: I'm running win 8.1 and yes everything is spelt correctly.